# Tweet me for an invite: does this mean direct messaging in Twitter

Tags: twitter

I was instructed to tweet an admin for an invite:

> there is an iot stack exchange, iot.stackexchange.com, currently in
>   private beta (tweet me @XXXX for an invite), where this would be
>   on-topic. I'm not sure if we can take migrations whils in private
>   beta..

Does this imply direct messaging?  I could not do this because this person does not 'follow me'. Is there any other mechanism for 1:1 messaging or is the only option to tweet, where everyone would see the conversation?

Answer (score 1):

Public tweet is the only option.